# Learn SQL The Hard Way - Exercise 2 - Creating Multitable DB - .schema command

Tags: sql, sqlite, schema

[I understand the sql in this exercise](http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex2.html) perfectly, but the setup type tasks are confusing to me.  Zed asks you to use the following SQL to create the following tables in a new database that are related by the id key. I'm fine there.

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT,
    last_name TEXT,
    age INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE pet (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    breed TEXT,
    age INTEGER,
    dead INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE person_pet (
    person_id INTEGER,
    pet_id INTEGER
);
```

In my windows command prompt I entered:

```
C:\SQLite> sqlite3 ex2.db < ex2.sql
```

ex2.db is my new db and ex2.sql contains the create statements listed above.

Zed then asks you to enter .schema using the sqlite command prompt. Nothing happens for me. It does not dump. Does .schema only work with Linux or OSX? I'm on windows.

The following is what he says you should get:

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT,
    last_name TEXT,
    age INTEGER
);
CREATE TABLE person_pet (
    person_id INTEGER,
    pet_id INTEGER
);
CREATE TABLE pet (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    breed TEXT,
    age INTEGER,
    dead INTEGER
);
sqlite>
```

Instead, this is what I get:

```
sqlite> .schema
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to start the `sqlite3` tool with:

```
C:\SQLite> sqlite3 ex2.sb
sqlite> .schema
...
```

Without a database file name, `sqlite3` just creates a temporary database.

Comment: Yes, this part isn't explained. I tried opening a separate instance of sqlite. Thansk and enjoy your points!

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows command prompt type:

```
C:\SQLite> sqlite3 ex3.db
```

sqlite will open.

```
sqlite> .schema
```

Create statements will display.